# Split a large 3rd party dll into smaller pieces

Tags: c#, .net, split, .net-assembly, ilmerge

Im trying to use a 3rd party .net 4.6 dll in my project. The dll is 40mb in size and everything works fine.

However the application which loads my dll has a bug in it which crashes when a loaded dll is greater than 10mb. This is being fixed but wont be ready for a while.

For the sake of not stalling my project is it possible to split a .NET assembly into smaller chunks but still have the referencing assembly load everything properly?

Comment: Apparently mono's linker might be able to help (see [this](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentalReducingTheSizeOfNETCoreApplicationsWithMonosLinker.aspx)).

Answer (score 5):

No, unless you can get your hands on the code and refactor it in pieces, which is highly unlikely.

You can *merge* assemblies, but you can't just randomly split them.